# How to sort XML data in an order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, get

I have a set of the list items that I would like to automatically display from high to low on page load. Ideally using jquery or javascript.

Here is my code.

data.xml

```
<cd>
  <presantage>10%</presantage>
</cd>
<cd> 
  <presantage>50%</presantage>
</cd>
<cd>
  <presantage>5%</presantage>
</cd>
```

For display xml data

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"data.xml",
        dataType:"xml",
        success:xmlParser2
    });
   });
   function xmlParser2(xml){
    xml = $(xml).children();
    $(xml).children().each(function () {

       let tag = $(this).prop("tagName");
        let presantage = '<div>' + $(this).find("presantage").text() + '</div>';

        let html = '<li>'+ (presantage)+'</li>';

            $(".list").append(html);
    });
}
```

For order elements

```
var ul = $(".list:first");
var arr = $.makeArray(ul.children("li"));

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    var textA = +$(a).text();
    var textB = +$(b).text();

    if (textA < textB) return -1;
    if (textA > textB) return 1;

    return 0;
});

ul.empty();

$.each(arr, function() {
    ul.append(this);
});
```

html

```
<ul class="list"></ul>
```

[Plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/X7Er706IJYu2oak7?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Comment: Ideally for javascript ;

Comment: `presantage` - typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 function xmlParser2(xml){
   var obj = {};

xml = $(xml).children();
$(xml).children().each(function () {

    obj[$(this).find("presantage").text().replace('%', '')]  = $(this).find("presantage").text();




});

for(var k in obj ){
    let html = '<li>'+ (obj[k])+'</li>';

    $(".list").append(html);
}

// alert(JSON.stringify(obj)) 
}
```

Comment: how is this sorting the `presantage`s?

Comment: Object keys are by default sorted in JS just like Array keys in PHP.

Comment: My bad. I overlooked `replace` call. Thanks. +1

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple JS (pure) code to get percentages sorted in desc order.

```
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "application/xml");
var elements = doc.getElementsByTagName('presantage');
var percentages = [];
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    percentages.push(parseFloat(elements[i].textContent));
}
percentages.sort((a, b) => b - a); // array [50, 10, 5]
```

After this you can sort loop over `percentages` and create your list html.

Note: if you need to sort in ascending order you would do `a - b`.

Comment: Where should I put in the code http://next.plnkr.co/edit/X7Er706IJYu2oak7?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview